# Find name of property owner in javascript

Tags: javascript

An example from some javascript course that I am following:

```
var Tornado = function(name, cities, degree) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cities = cities;
    this.degree = degree;
};

Tornado.prototype = {
    nCities: function() {
        return this.cities.length
    },
    valueOf: function() {
        return this.nCities() * this.degree;
    },
    toString: function() {
        return this.cities[0][0].toString() + " " + this.name;
    }
}

cities = [["Washington", 1], ["Rotterdam", 2]]

var x = new Tornado("crazy", cities, 3)
console.log(x.nCities())
console.log(x.valueOf())
console.log(x + 16)
console.log(x.toString() + "... wow!")


Object.prototype.findOwnerOfProperty = function(propName) {
    var currentObject = this;
    while(currentObject !== null) {
        if(currentObject.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
            return currentObject;
        } else {
            currentObject = currentObject.__proto__;
        }
    }
    return "No property found!";
};

console.log(x.findOwnerOfProperty("toString"));
```

The `findOwnerOfProperty` function returns the object where the property is defined. This is nice, but it would be nicer to also have the name of that object (Tornado.prototype in this example), how can I do that?

Comment: Impossible. Objects don't have names. Imagine if I did `var t = x`, then what's the "name" of that Tornado instance?

Comment: Override the toString() for the class, return the "class-name" (i.e [Object Tornado]) from this function. Now when you return this object, then on calling toString() of it, you can get the name.

Answer (score 0):

No built-in solution. but you can make a property

```
this._constructor = arguments.callee.name;
```

inside Tornado function and make a

```
getConstructor:function(){

   return this._constructor;  

}
```

inside prototype. 
BTW , forgot to mention that you should remake

```
var Tornado = function
```

to:

```
function Tornado
```

Comment: `arguments.callee.name;` does not work in `'strict mode';`.

Comment: than it should be even more complicated xD